# Get max value from table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am applying this query:

```
$this->db->select_max('product_id');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

to get max value from table.

But when i add this result to db in another table. like this:

```
$this->db->insert('images',$product_id);
```

It show this error:
Error Number: 1054

```
Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `images` (`product_id`) VALUES (Array)

Filename: C:\wamp\www\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

I am using codeigniter.

Comment: please post your controller and model code for better understand your problem

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you are inserting an Array instead of an actual value, so why don't you check $product_id before inserting? You are not showing us the code that gets $product_id from the result, and there's the issue.

Comment: php It's telling you that `$product_id` is an array, use `print_r($product_id)` to see which values it contains.

Comment: When I did var dump it shows: array(1) { ["product_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (1) { ["product_id"]=> string(2) "26" } } }

Comment: And I want last this means 26 only.

Comment: You were passing an array directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying an array within input here's I have updated your code

**Model Code**

```
$this->db->select_max('product_id');
$this->db->from('products');
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

**Controller Code**

```
$product_id = $this->Product_area_model->get_product_id();
$data['product_id'] = $product_id[0]['product_id'];
$result = $this->your_model->foo($data);
```

**Model Code**

```
function foo($data = ''){
   $this->db->insert('images',$data);
   return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: would you please tell me the purpose of $data = '' in this line 
function foo($data = '')

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work for you...

```
$this->db->insert('images',$product_id[0]['product_id']);
```

Comment: How you know the nature  and type of array??

Comment: @saty I think it always return `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter allows you to specify an **array of values** as the data to insert, but I think your issue is that you're inserting an **array of arrays**.

If that's the case then use the **batch** function...

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data); 

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'), ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```